# Flutter make page exit transition dynamic/variable

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

All the resources I can find on page transitions for flutter involve defining a page's exit transition at the time the page is created, but I want my page to either exit screen left or screen right depending on what page the user is navigating to next.

I have three screens and I want them to slide horizontally to appear as if they are in a row - I'm using the bottom navigation bar, so I want them to slide and push each other out horizontally, but the default transition has them stack on top of the previous screen and slide in from the bottom.

To be clear, when the user is on the middle page and clicks a tab to the right of the current tab, I want the current page to exit to the left and the new page to enter from the right; if the user is clicks a tab to the left, I want the current page to exit to the right and the new page to enter from the left. This means the middle page could exit to the left or the right, depending on what the next page is.

I have the following code, which does the entrance transitions correctly, but the exit transitions are getting set based on how the page was navigated to, not how the page is being navigated away from.

```
Route routeSlideIn(Widget destinationPage, int direction) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => destinationPage,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const curve = Curves.ease;
      final curveIn = CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animation,
        curve: curve,
      );
      final curveOut = CurvedAnimation(
          parent: secondaryAnimation,
          curve: curve
      );

      if (direction > 0) {
        final tweenIn = Tween(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset.zero);
        final tweenOut = Tween(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(-1, 0));

        return SlideTransition(
          position: tweenIn.animate(curveIn),
          child: SlideTransition(
              position: tweenOut.animate(curveOut),
              child: child
          ),
        );
      } else {
        final tweenIn = Tween(begin: Offset(-1, 0), end: Offset.zero);
        final tweenOut = Tween(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(1, 0));

        return SlideTransition(
          position: tweenIn.animate(curveIn),
          child: SlideTransition(
              position: tweenOut.animate(curveOut),
              child: child
          ),
        );
      }

    },

  );
}
```

The function is being called in a nested navigator for the page with the bottom navigation bar, with

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            var direction = 1;
            if (settings.arguments != null) {
              direction = (settings.arguments as StudentRouterArgs).direction;
            }

            late Widget page;
            switch (settings.name) {
              case null:
              case "/":
              case FirstPage.routeName:
                page = FirstPage();
                break;
              case SecondPage.routeName:
                page = SecondPage();
                break;
              case ThirdPage.routeName:
                page = ThirdPage();
                break;
              default:
                throw Exception('Unknown route: ${settings.name}');
            }

            return routeSlideIn(page, direction);
          },
```

and then to change the route:

```
_navigatorKey.currentState!.pushReplacementNamed(
              destination,
              arguments: StudentRouterArgs(index - oldIndex)
          );
```

I've found that the slide transition class can have a Listener object, but I've never used a Listener object before so I'm not sure if that's a valid solution or how I would even use it. Ideally it would be nice if the PageRouteBuilder could define the exit animation for the page that's being replaced, and not the exit animation for the page that's coming in, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

What's the best way to achieve this variable exit transition?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed the [coordinated_page_route](https://pub.dev/packages/coordinated_page_route) package for this exact purpose. It's usage in your case would look something like this:

1. Add a `CoordinatedRouteObserver` to the observer list in your parent Navigator:

```
Navigator(
        observers: 
        [
          CoordinatedRouteObserver() // <--- This must go here!
        ],
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {  },
      ));
```

2. In your `onGenerateRoute` you'd simply need to check the direction and push the appropriate route:

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            var direction = 1;
            if (settings.arguments != null) {
              direction = (settings.arguments as StudentRouterArgs).direction;
            }

            late Widget page;
            switch (settings.name) {
              case null:
              case "/":
              case FirstPage.routeName:
                page = FirstPage();
                break;
              case SecondPage.routeName:
                page = SecondPage();
                break;
              case ThirdPage.routeName:
                page = ThirdPage();
                break;
              default:
                throw Exception('Unknown route: ${settings.name}');
            }

            if (direction > 0) return ForwardPushRoute((context) => page);
            else if (direction < 0) return BackwardPushRoute((context) => page);
            else {
              // Its up to you how to handle this case (throw an exception, push a "neutral" route, push an "error" route, or something else)
            }
          },
```

The previous page should now slide out in the appropriate direction.